# Why am is laravel throwing an SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-query-builder

Am running a query builder on my laravel app using inner join
But Laravel keeps throwing errors, i tested the MySql Query
i wrote directly in my database using phpMyAdmin it works fine

```
SELECT 
    u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.username, u.sponsor,u.deleted_at, i.id as investment_id, i.total_amount, i.created_at
FROM
    users AS u 
JOIN investments as i ON 
    i.id= ( SELECT i1.id FROM investments as i1 where u.id=i1.user_id and i1.status ='confirmed' ORDER BY i1.created_at LIMIT 1)
WHERE
    u.sponsor = '901d08da-e6c4-476a-ae7b-9386990b8b9e' AND u.deleted_at is NULL
ORDER BY 
    created_at DESC
```

but when i write it using query builder it wont work.

```
$refered_users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('investments', function ($join) {
      $join->on('users.id', '=', 'investments.user_id')
      ->where('investment.status', '=', 'confirmed')
      ->orderBy('investment.created_at','desc')->first();
    })
    ->select('users.id,users.first_name,users.last_name,users.username,users.sponsor,investment.id AS investment_id,investment.total_amount,investment.created_at')
    ->where('users.sponsor','=',Auth::User()->id)
    ->orderBy('investment.created_at','desc')
    ->paginate(10);
```

i tried a RAW `DB::select()` and it works but i want to use the query builder so i can paginate the results.
this is how my table is arranged:

> **users** 
>   `id, first_name, last_name, username, sponsor(id of another user), created_at, deleted_at`
>
> **investments**
>   `id, total_amount , user_id(id of a user), status, created_at, deleted_at`

Am not much Good with SQL Queries so if am writing it all wrong please don't scold just, try to explain a lil bit more so i can understand

this is the error coming out:

> **Illuminate\Database\QueryException**
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'on `users`.`id` = `investments`.`user_id` and
>   `investment`.`status` = ? order by' at line 1 (SQL: select * on
>   `users`.`id` = `investments`.`user_id` and `investment`.`status` =
>   confirmed order by `investment`.`created_at` desc limit 1)

output of the dd

```
select first_name,last_name,username,deleted_at,total_amount,
investment_created_at,user_id from `users` 
inner join (select user_id,total_amount,status,created_at AS investment_created_at from `investments` 
where `status` = ? and `investments`.`deleted_at` is null) as `confirmed_investments` 
on `users`.`id` = `confirmed_investments`.`user_id` 
where `sponsor` = ? order by `investment_created_at` desc ◀`


`array:2 [▼ 0 => "confirmed" 1 => "901d08da-e6c4-476a-ae7b-9386990b8b9e" ]`
```

am using:

> PHP version: 7.3.1
>
> MySql Version: 8.0.18

Comment: Replace `paginate(10)` with `dd()`. Add the output to your question so we can see the full query it's running. Sample data and migrations would help too. A lot of this could likely be done with Eloquent relationships.

Comment: But first thing I would do is get rid of the `orderBy()` and `first()` calls in your subjoin. Doesn't make any sense to have it there. Maybe you want those on `$confirmed_investments` instead.

Comment: @miken32 heres i updated the question with the output of the dd()

Comment: @miken32 i moved the `orderBy()` and `first()` to `$confirmed_investments` now it's empty results...if you can aid me convert the sql query to query builder i'd be happy, i don't want to use raw sql and create a pagination my self because the records from the query might become very large in the future to process with php.

Comment: Add migrations and sample data, as well as expected output. Are you trying to find earliest confirmed investment with a given sponsor? Will there be multiple matches or just one?

Answer (score 1):

You can get query of your code and compare it to your desired query like this:

```
$refered_users = DB::table('users')
->join('investments', function ($join) {
  $join->on('users.id', '=', 'investments.user_id')
  ->where('investment.status', '=', 'confirmed')
  ->orderBy('investment.created_at','desc')->first();
})
->select('users.id,users.first_name,users.last_name,users.username,users.sponsor,investment.id AS investment_id,investment.total_amount,investment.created_at')
->where('users.sponsor','=',Auth::User()->id)
->orderBy('investment.created_at','desc')
->toSql();
```

Your join query is getting data for `id` by running another query. I think you need to use sub query. If you are using laravel > 6 it is on documentation.

Comment: it's out completely different compared to the query i wrote...
i've tried the sub query's am not that good that way either, if you could aid me convert the mysql query into laravel's query builder method i'll appreciate it deeply, Thanks

Comment: Thanks @train_fox i finally got it to work, wasn't easy ;)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Sorry, i was not available earlier.

Comment: Can't figure out how to limit the result from the investment table to oldest only for each users:
i just updated the Query Builder to the new one, the issue is the limiter for each investment record:
`->orderByDesc('confirmed_investments.investment_created_at')->first();`
@train_fox

Comment: Maybe this can help you: `->orderByDesc('confirmed_investments.investment_created_at')->limit(1);`

Comment: thanks didnt work either, made a temporay fix for now, used DB::Select with manual lengthAwarePagination....won't hold up if the records grow large